# Javascript open a new page(one or many), wait for it to load, then close it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing an application that can "bump" threads on a website at a specific interval. The application looks at multiple input boxes and if there is a value in each one it does a window.open command to load the page. It then closes the page. The problem i am running into is that I don't see any way to pause my for loop after each execution so the page never actually loads before it gets closed. Any ideas? Here is the code.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Reoccuring Open</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Bump0" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump1" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump2" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump3" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump4" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump5" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump6" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Bump7" type="text" /><br />

<input type="button" id="btnStartReoccure" value="Start" onclick="fncSetInterval()"/> <br />
<br />
    If Checked will continue to run<input type="checkbox" id="chxReoccure" />
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function fncSetInterval() {
        //alert("Set interval x " + x);
        i = 14410000; // 4 hours and some extra
        var bumpsValue = new Array;

        for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {
            if (document.getElementById("Bump" + x).value == null || document.getElementById("Bump" + x).value == "") {
                break;
            }
            bumpsValue[x] = document.getElementById("Bump" + x).value;

            window[x] = window.open("http://www.somewebpage.com/bump.php?t=" + bumpsValue[x]);

        }

        window.setInterval(function(){fncRunReOccur()},i);

    }



    function fncRunReOccur() {

        //var RecURL = document.getElementById("ReoccuranceURL").value;
        //alert("(document.getElementById.value " + (document.getElementById("chxReoccure").checked));
        if (document.getElementById("chxReoccure").checked == true) {

        }
    }

    function fncSleep(millis, callback) {
        setTimeout(function ()
        { callback(); }
        , millis);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: A script to bump forum threads? I very much dislike that notion.

Comment: There are a lot of people that are going to dislike this notion. Regardless of the dislike does anyone know how to get it to work? I can just write another entire function that waits a few minutes longer and then closes the open windows but i was wondering if someone had a way to make it work as is. Without jquery :).